# Android: cannot access Tomcat server through Android app

Tags: android, tomcat

I am not able to access Tomcat server through my app, however I am able to open the same URL in my mobile browser. My laptop and mobile both are connected to same router. Also the url which is commented is accessible through app.

WebService:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class FirstTest {
 @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
hit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JSONClass().execute("http://192.168.0.100:8081/TrekServerTest2/rest/hello");
            //new JSONClass().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
        }
    });
}


public class JSONClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            httpURLConnection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream stream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line="";
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "wrongUrl";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "connError";
        }
        finally {
            if(httpURLConnection!=null)
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            try {
                if(reader!=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "closeError";
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        tv.setText(s);

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
     02-04 17:44:25.922 724-967/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateSavedNetworkHistory():  try "Logon broadband GP"WPA_PSK SSID="Logon broadband GP" Logon broadband GP [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPS][ESS] ajst=0
 02-04 17:44:25.922 724-967/? E/WifiConfigStore:         got known scan result 0c:d2:b5:51:82:c6 key : "Logon broadband GP"WPA_PSK num: 1 rssi=-65 freq=2417
 02-04 17:44:25.942 724-967/? E/WifiAutoJoinController: status: bssid=0c:d2:b5:51:82:c6
                                                   freq=2417
                                                   ssid=Logon broadband GP
                                                   id=9
                                                   mode=station
                                                   pairwise_cipher=CCMP
                                                   group_cipher=TKIP
                                                   key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
                                                   wpa_state=COMPLETED
                                                   ip_address=192.168.0.104
                                                   p2p_device_address=02:0e:41:4c:1d:2b
                                                   address=00:0e:41:4c:1d:2b
                                                   uuid=c753c5e7-fbf6-58ae-b610-23d41c19c3e4
 02-04 17:44:25.948 724-967/? E/WifiAutoJoinController: attemptAutoJoin() num recent config 1 current="Logon broadband GP"WPA_PSK ---> suppNetId=9
 02-04 17:44:25.948 724-967/? E/WifiAutoJoinController: Done attemptAutoJoin status=0
 02-04 17:44:25.951 724-967/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:15 needWrite=false
 02-04 17:44:26.059 724-967/? E/WifiStateMachine:  ConnectedState (when=-2ms what=131155 arg1=29!CMD_RSSI_POLL 29 0 "Logon broadband GP" 0c:d2:b5:51:82:c6 rssi=-64 f=2417 sc=60 link=135 tx=0.0, 0.0, 0.0  rx=0.3 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1378] from screen [on:0 period:151781643] gl hn u24 rssi=-59 ag=0 hr    ticks 0,0,399 ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
```

Comment: what does your logcat says?

Comment: should that be `http://192.168.0.100:8081` (missing "//")

Comment: While copying i deleted by mistake, even after putting "//" it is not working. If you could see this post and suggest anything. That would be very helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921738/android-cannot-call-java-web-service-through-app?noredirect=1#comment71026412_41921738

Comment: In general I'd strongly recommend you use something like `Retrofit` rather than writing your own implementation.

Comment: @NayanSrivastava....There is no error in logcat..I am getting connError message in return while running.

Comment: ensure you gave permission to access Internet in manifest, your log cat will help us to give appropriate answer

Comment: @saravananr..edited the post with logcat

Comment: `..I am getting connError message `. So you have an error! Where and when exactly? The logcat you posted has nothing to do with your problem. Please try again.

Comment: `even after putting "//" it is not working.`. Please edit your post!

Comment: .`.I am getting connError message`. No not at all! That is your own error. You should have told us that you catch an IOException. Moreover you should have told us the value of e.getMessage(). And also return that as you throw away valuable info. All is also clearly visible in the logcat so post the right lines please.

Comment: @greenapps..In getMessage() I am getting the following response: failed to connect to /192.168.0.100 (port 8081) after 90000msL isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (no route to host)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what the mistake was in my case. Looks like I was using the wrong ip address all the time. The ip which I got through ipconfig was not of the common router to which the laptop and my device was connected. I tried using the ip from properties of the connected wifi, and voila!..it worked. Thank you all for your efforts.